# SEF Routing in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a small TV Show application where I want to have the show name (slug) in the URL.

Currently when I list all the shows the URL to the show is `/shows/{show_id}`. That's not really how I want it routed.

Example how I want it to be:
`/shows/{show_name}` where `show_name` is a field on the `Show` model.

In my `routes.php` I simply use `Route::resource('shows','ShowsController');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use a route binding:

```
Route::bind('show', function($value, $route) {
    return Show::where('show_name', $value)
      ->first();
});
```

and individual routes:

```
Route::get('shows/{show}', 'ShowsController@getShow');
```

I don't believe resource routing can be used in combination with bindings at this time.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `Route::controller` instead of `Route::get`? This will work, but it's far from the elegance I want to achieve

Comment: @Ortixx I haven't tried `Route::controller` with bindings. You're welcome to, I just can't guarantee it works right. I have a personal preference for explicit, me-defined routes rather than Laravel's magic ones.